# Django- Write Custom Error Messages For Model Fields

Tags: django, django-models

I Want To Write A Custom Error Message For One Of My Model Filds.

My Code Is:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = 'Car Name', error_messages = {'blank': 'Please Insert Your Car Name'})
```

But This Code Don't Work.

How can I Fix It?

And Another Question Is, Is It Work For `ModelForm`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works on my computer. When I call the clean_fields method on an instance of the car model, I got the right error message. I use django version 1.3.1.

Comment: Can you give the error messages you get ? I really don't know why this should not work.

Comment: How do you test your model ? I tested it by using the command  python manage.py shell. Then I created an instance in ipython.

Comment: No, I Test It In Admin Panel. It Must Shown When I Don't Insert Anything To `name` Field.